# Please explain a strange interaction between bytefield, unicode-math, and mathtools

Tags: amsmath, unicode-math, mathtools, bytefield

`bytefield` gives me different results when used in association with `mathtools` and `unicode-math` *when used together*. Here's my 'good' MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools}    % This breaks things
%\usepackage{unicode-math} % when used with this
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}{16}
  \bitheader{0,15}\\
  \begin{rightwordgroup}{Header}    
  \bitbox{16}{Without}\\
  \bitbox{16}{Etc}
  \end{rightwordgroup}\\
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

If I run this as-is, I get:

[image: Good result]

Now, if I uncomment *both* the lines marked, the alignment of the brace goes wonky:

[image]

Either `unicode-math` or `mathtools` *alone* doesn't produce this effect.

Any ideas, please?

---

As noted by @Qrrbrbirlbel, you can get exactly the same behaviour by swapping `amsmath` for `mathtools`.

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: @enthdegree : I cloned a new from an old document (and preamble). The new document needed a bytefield diagram, which formatted badly (as above). I then built an MWE using the same preamble, and, commenting and uncommenting lumps of the preamble, found the two lines that made it happen and unhappen.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Another mistery. If you compile the provided MWE (with the two conflicting packages commented out) with pdflatex and xelaatex, you get the same result. But if you use lualatex you get a bigger and badly positioned brace. This suggest a font problem, but a diff of the .log files shows no significative differences...

Comment: @JLDiaz : Thank you! I'll open that as a separate question. (Later, I'm a bit bogged down now with the catastrophic announcement from Google)

Comment: There is code loaded by `unicode-math` that is only run if `amsmath` is loaded, and furthercode that is only run if `mathtools` is loaded.  See the files `unicode-math-xetex.sty` and `unicode-math-luatex.sty`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit2: Complete rewrite, with mostly complete explanation of all the intricacies.

This is due to [a complication in how XeTeX decides what fontdimen parameter to use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115103/2707), as Heiko notes in his answer to that question.  In another answer, Khaled Hosny confirms that the details are buggy.

To center the brace vertically, `bytefield` sets the `\fontdimen22` of `\textfont2`, which indicates the position of the math axis, to 0pt.  This works perfectly fine for old-style fonts, but not for OpenType ones, which have plenty other parameters to work with (and parameters are ordered differently).

If `unicode-math` is not loaded, then the font used is old-style, and the correct fontdimen parameter is used.

If `unicode-math` is loaded, then the math font is an OpenType font (by default `latinmodern-math.otf`), so we could expect problems, but XeTeX has the ability to remap fontdimen parameters to make TeX (and `bytefield`) happy.  This requires a mapping both when retrieving the values and when storing them.  Everything(?) works fine so far.

Let us make an aside now.  When turning a math list into boxes (as described in Appendix G of the TeXbook), (Xe)TeX looks at fontdimen parameters of various math fonts, most importantly `\textfont2` (and `\script(script)font2`, and the `\...font3` analogs).  Well, really, I am not sure what parameters XeTeX looks at.  Of course, it needs to consider different parameters depending on the type of font, and Khaled Hosny seems to be saying that the last defined font is tested for whether it is OpenType or old-style.  This is a bug.

As long as we don't load any additional font within math mode, the last defined font has the right type, and the correct fontdimen parameter, which was set to 0pt, is used to place the math axis.  As the example in [my question quoted above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115103/2707) shows, storing some text in a box, even without doing anything with the box, and without performing any (TeX) assignment, has an effect on setting the math material.  As we can expect given the nature of the bug, the font in which the "text in a box" is set affects the outer result, since it changes whether the last font was OpenType or old-style.

Now, where does `amsmath` come in?  It defines `\resetMathstrut@`, which rebuilds a box of height and depth equal to that of a line (like `\strut`, but for math mode), and places a call to that function at `\every@math@size` (not sure when that is called exactly, but somewhere within math mode).  The definition is not terribly clear, but let me explain it.

```
\def\resetMathstrut@
  {%
    \setbox \z@ \hbox
      {%
        \mathchardef \@tempa \mathcode `\(\relax
        \def \@tempb ##1"##2##3{\the \textfont "##3\char "}%
        \expandafter \@tempb \meaning \@tempa \relax
      }%
    \ht \Mathstrutbox@ \ht \z@
    \dp \Mathstrutbox@ \dp \z@
  }
```

The code stores a horizontal box containing a parenthesis into the box `\z@` ("short-hand" for 0), then sets the height `\ht` and depth `\dp` of the `\Mathstrutbox@` equal to those of the new box `\z@`, making that box's vertical dimensions be that of a parenthesis.  How is the parenthesis typeset?  Well, the math code of `(` is converted to hexadecimal thanks to how TeX displays the `\meaning` of the `\mathchar` token `\@tempa` (namely as `\mathchar"` and hexadecimal digits... would the `amsmath` code fail with a math active parenthesis?).  Then load the `\textfont` number `##3` (in hexadecimal), which is the math font for `(` (as extracted from the hexadecimal digits), and typeset whichever character of that font is a right parenthesis (again using part of the math code).  Nowhere in this process has math mode been entered, but the math font was selected, within the box.

We are ready now.  When `amsmath` is loaded, `unicode-math` makes extra redefinitions, in particular of `\resetMathstrut@`, which becomes

```
\def\resetMathstrut@
  {%
    \setbox \z@ \hbox {$($}%
    \ht \Mathstrutbox@ \ht \z@
    \dp \Mathstrutbox@ \dp \z@
  }
```

That definition is much simpler, and does essentially the same as the `amsmath` version: typeset a parenthesis with the math font, and use its height and depth to set the dimensions of the `\Mathstrutbox@`.  Naively, the only thing that could happen is that the `\everymath` token register (renamed to `\frozen@everymath` by LaTeX) contained global assignments, which clashed with the surrounding maths (well, `\everyhbox` could also play a role, but does not).  This would be a bug in LaTeX.  But LaTeX has been used extensively, and the code is now robust against nesting math modes (`source2e` has interesting comments on that).   I was thus a bit puzzled, and even more so when finding out that even emptying `\frozen@everymath` before the inner math mode did not fix the interference.

Of course, having read the above, the astute reader can guess what happens, a dozen hours faster than me: the nested math, which should not have any influence on the surrounding math list, mixes up the fontdimen parameters because of the XeTeX bug.

Since I don't fully understand the details of the XeTeX behaviour, I am not sure whether the fix that I proposed earlier (reverting the old definition of `\resetMathstrut@` after `unicode-math` is loaded) would work in all cases or just happens to work.  I don't know either whether it is possible to patch `bytefield`, or any other macro, to make your document work properly.  Depending on the details of what test XeTeX does, and on what font, it may be impossible to correct the behaviour at the macro level.

In the meantime, here is a code that might work, saving `\resetMathstrut@` before `unicode-math` and restoring it afterwards.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\let\oldresetMathstrut@\resetMathstrut@
\makeatother
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\makeatletter
\let\resetMathstrut@\oldresetMathstrut@
\makeatother
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}{16}
  \bitheader{0,15}\\
  \begin{rightwordgroup}{Header}
  \bitbox{16}{Without}\\
  \bitbox{16}{Etc}
  \end{rightwordgroup}\\
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for dedicating some serious thought to this.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I've updated my answer, trying to add details of the behaviour.  I don't know if there is a fix other tan waiting for Khaled Hosny to have time to address the issue.

Comment: It [appears to be fixed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115103/#comment815269_115140) perhaps in the latest XeTeX (not sure when it will reach TeXLive users using `tlmgr`).