# Why is the fraction off the math axis in XeTeX?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, unicode, unicode-math

The fraction in textstyle is off the math axis in XeTeX when I use a Unicode math font.  In LuaTeX, though, it aligns nicely with the math axis.  The follwing MWE should illustrate this.  Also, in displaystyle everything is fine.

```
\ifdefined\directlua
  \input luaotfload.sty
\fi
$-{1\over 2}$%
\font\ms="Latin Modern Math:script=math;+ssty=0" at 7pt
\scriptfont0=\ms
$-{1\over 2}$
\bye
```

Here you can see the output for XeTeX and LuaTeX:

> [image]
>
> [image]

How can I fix this?  Does it suffice to adjust `\fontdimen` parameters?

---

This does not only happen in plain XeTeX, but also in LaTeX with the `unicode-math` package.  Unfortunately, I cannot show a side-by-side comparison here, because `unicode-math` immediately changes the math font to “Latin Modern Math”.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$-\frac{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

---

As can be seen from Herbert's reply, the problem also occurs in other situations.  Here I collect an incomplete list of questions reporting similar issues:

- [\setbox containing maths interferes with surrounding math mode in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115103)
- [\scriptstyle affects \overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323517)
- [Bug in xelatex + unicode+math + vphantom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296177)
- [Bug in xelatex + unicode-math + xits + \vphantom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296061)
- [xelatex + unicode-math + stackengine + \big = ↯](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375355)

---

Unfortunately, the problem was not entirely fixed and messed up fontdimens still turn up in some places.

- [Subscript placement with unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374771)
- [Discrepancy between lualatex and xelatex regarding display math vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423078/)

Comment: There's evidently some problem in computing the `\fontdimen` parameters.

Comment: The `at 7pt` seems to scale the fontdimen (try out 3pt for a more pronounced effect).

Comment: @egreg Which `\fontdimen` is responsible  for that?  I can only find ones for raising or lowering numerator and denominator but none for the bar or axis.  Also setting, e.g., `\fontdimen42\scriptfont0=10pt` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I think this is a good one for the XeTeX mailing list at http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/xetex. It seems that XeTeX is using `\fontdimen22` pertaining to `\scriptfont2` instead of `\textfont2`.

Comment: IIRC, there's a difference between lua +ssty (scriptstyle!) and xetex; ie for lua: 2 and xetex: 1 or something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the development version of XeTeX (looks like it was the same underlying issue as [\setbox containing maths interferes with surrounding math mode in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115103/729)):

[image]

Comment: This is great news!  I'll mark your answer as accepted once TL 2017 is released which will probably contain the fixed version.

Comment: Was it you who fixed this bug?  The person who corrected this deserves a reward I think.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Jonathan Kew fixed it (and a few other math bugs). It was me, however, who introduced this bug in the first place, so I guess this makes me deserve the reverse of being rewarded.

Comment: Don't worry :) Can you maybe point me to the corresponding diffs and commits in the code?  I'd like to study in detail what was wrong.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I’m not 100% sure which commit fixed it, but my guess is [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/code/ci/9785737384bfe6080b8231f666ddf5b3861c957a/tree/source/texk/web2c/xetexdir/xetex.web?diff=352a4408c93acf66efe8eac9e45c259b1c7cf7cd&diformat=sidebyside).

Answer (score 13):

I played a bit ... black is `xelatex` and red `lualatex` and yes, this is not an answer ...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-1.6ex}{\includegraphics{xetex}}}%
\textcolor{red}{$-\frac12=-\dfrac12=-\tfrac12$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ugh… I used this approach to test `luatex`, `xetex`, and `pdftex` against Knuth `tex` and it turned out that `tex`, `pdftex`, and `luatex` overlay exactly, whereas `xetex` is off, as shown in your picture.  That is to say, that math typesetting with Unicode math fonts is inherently broken in XeTeX.

Comment: After some more playing, I found that this is also related to the “`at 7pt`”.  For some reason even the spacings between the math atoms are scaled by that factor.  But even after that there is a small difference left, cf. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75e5b006effae7d3b860