# Unicode math at TeX primitive level

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, unicode-math

I am looking for information how to implement Math OTF font in XeTeX or LuaTeX
at TeX primitive level (using XeTeX or LuaTeX primitives). There exist a LaTeX package unicode-math.
Unfortunatelly, this package is LaTeX oriented, documentation is at LaTeX user
level and implementation in LaTeX3 language which is far from TeX primitives.
So, the inspiration from this package is impossible for me.

Where can I find such information?

I try to be more specific what I am looking for. The principles of math
typesetting in TeX can be summarized by:

- You must set (at least) math family 2 and 3 using \font, \textfont, \scriptfont and
  \scripscriptfont primitives. The metric of such fonts must include more
  \fontdimens than basic 7 (dim 8--22 for family 2 and dim 8--13 in family 3,
  they are used as described in appendix G in the TeXbook).
- Each elementary math object can be a "character" decladed by \matcode or a
  "control sequence" declared by \mathchardef. The data points to type of the
  object (used for horizontal spacing) and to the family plus slot of the font.
- The \delimiter code must point to family plus slot. There are pointers
  to create a queue of consecutive characters (big to bigger brackes). These pointers are in font metric of used font and the queue can ends by special
  pointers for components of a bracket of arbitrary size. Similar principle is used for radicals queue.
- The \mathop type of objects can point to the family plus slot where two
  variant sizes of big operators are. They are connected by pointers inside font
  metric.

So, this is (roughly speaking) the basic information about background of math
typesetting at TeX primitive level. But these informations are useless for me
when I am working with (say) texgyrepagella-math.otf. Where are the pointers of brackets or radical queues? Where are extended font dimens?

Of course, I know how to load this font using extended syntax of \font primitive, I can set a
font feature using \font primitive and I know that there exists primitives
\Umathchar and \Umathchardef. But this is very few information. This is
insufficient to declare basic unicode math typesetting.

Is there any info like I mentioned above, but for unicode math?

Comment: The concept of families does not apply for Unicode math fonts.  This [github Gist](https://gist.github.com/morbusg/9388664) by @morbusg might help you.

Comment: LuaTeX and XeTeX are rather different here as LuaTeX requires all of the mechanisms of a font loader to be provided first. Given the fact the question is specifically about doing 'everything at a low level' that seems unlikely to be useful. At the same time the requirements of the two engines are somewhat different. Would it be OK to limit the question to XeTeX (where everything is done in TeX)?

Comment: @HenriMenke No, but you do have to have a subset of values defined!

Comment: @JosephWright Unicode math typesetting is [broken in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549/why-is-the-fraction-off-the-math-axis-in-xetex).  It would therefore make more sense to use LuaTeX for this endeavour.

Comment: Also, are we allowed to use pre-defined data files/loaders (in particular I'm thinking of `load-unicode-math-classes.tex`, written entirely in primitives)?

Comment: @HenriMenke Unicode math setting is not entirely reliable in either XeTeX or LuaTeX: both have issues when compared to pdfTeX/classical fonts.

Comment: @JosephWright `load-unicode-math-classes.tex` expands to `Umathcode` repeatedly used. This is simple. But main question is where are radicals, brackets and extended fontdimens. And where it is documented.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- the otf math table is broken with respect to the necessary font parameters for extended delimiters.  we're working on it (but not sure we can be optimistic since microsoft is in charge of the otf math table definitions; we are very discouraged).

Comment: @JosephWright wrote: "Unicode math setting is not entirely reliable." I understand it that there are not reliable usage of (say) Pagella-Math. Sure?

Comment: @wipet I mean 'This area is still actively being developed: there are bugs', which contrasts with the TeX90 situation. (Bugs may be in the fonts or the loaders, which makes life somewhat tricky.) Depending on ones use case it may be fine.

Comment: @wipet an opentype font specifies the equivalent of fontdimens in the math table within the font so you require the engine (or lua) to interpret this the spec for the math table is https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/math.htm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hoped that this specification can be out of my mind when there are good documented primitives they can be used for math typesetting. In *TeX, I cannot to access the data from this specification. I must use a primitives. What primitives?

Comment: One *can* use families with math OTF. There was some spacing issues IIRC, I think I have a question here for that.

Comment: @wipet --  you might find these slides (from bachotex 2009) of interest: [Open Type Math Illuminated](http://tug.org/~vieth/papers/bachotex2009/ot-math-talk.pdf).  see in particular p.19, where the absence of some required tex parameters for large delimiters is reported.

Comment: Not sure I see the [tag:plain-tex] tag fitting here: isn't the question about _any_ format?

Comment: When somebody needs to load Unicode Math font in plain TeX, then the answer is here. The `unicode-math.sty` is unusable for plain TeX users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In classical TeX a number of math mode fonts are used to supply the output glyphs based on the input, and as observed in the question the relevant `\mathcode` of the input token. In contrast, when using a Unicode math mode font *only one font* is used to supply all of the glyphs. As such, rather than the limited number of slots available in a TeX font there are large number of math mode-specific entries in a Unicode font.

Both Unicode engines (XeTeX and LuaTeX) provide the primitive `\Umathcode` for setting the extended math codes required for this to work. Details are available in both the XeTeX and LuaTeX manual: the syntax is

```
\Umathcode ⟨char slot⟩ [=] ⟨math type⟩ ⟨fam.⟩ ⟨glyph slot⟩
```

Notice that there is a requirement to supply a family here but that these will all be the same.

To set up the font dimensions required for math mode working, the engine or a suitable loader has to read the table supplied by the font. In XeTeX this happens as part of the (extended) `\font` primitive, for example

```
\font\lmmx = "[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:mode=base;script=math;"
```

whilst in LuaTeX a Lua-based loader is required to extend the `\font` primitive (which out-of-the-box is identical to that in TeX90) (Realistically the font loader to use with LuaTeX is `luaotfload`, which is based on that written for ConTeXt but loadable with plain, LaTeX, _etc. There is work ongoing to use the HarfBuzz shaper with LuaTeX but this is not at present usable to my knowledge.)

As only one font is in use, conversion between input and output glyphs requires some differences from classical TeX. For example, input such as

```
$y = mx + c$
```

will *not* give italic letters unless they have the correct `\Umathcode` to point to the 'correct' codepoint. For example, we need

```
\Umathcode `\y =  "7 "1 "1D466
```

(I'm assuming that we will use font 1 for all glyphs: this is not required.)

Operators in Unicode math are scaled by the font shaper directly rather than needing extensible parts. As such, something like `\int` is defined for Unicode use by

```
\let\int=∫
```

with the correct math code then chosen

```
\Umathcode `∫= "1 "1 `∫
```

Both XeTeX and LuaTeX have the `\Uradical` primitive for radicals: LuaTeX also has `\Uroot`.

An important consequence of using only one font is that for example making symbols bold requires that all of the relevant math codes change. Thus setting up something `\bf` requires that we map over all code points affected and alter their `\Umathcode`.

Whilst only one font is required, it is necessary to define math families two and three to satisfy the engine that sufficient math parameters are available. (This may change, certainly in LuaTeX, as it seems to be a hold-over of code paths from TeX90.) At the same time, script fonts need to be loaded telling the loader what they are. This leads to a minimal font loading set up something like

```
\font\lmmx   = "[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:mode=base;script=math;" %
\font\lmmvii = "[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:mode=base;script=math;+ssty=0;" at 7pt %
\font\lmmv   = "[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:mode=base;script=math;+ssty=1;" at 5pt %
\textfont1 = \lmmx
\textfont2 = \lmmx
\textfont3 = \lmmx
\scriptfont1 = \lmmvii
\scriptfont2 = \lmmvii
\scriptfont3 = \lmmvii
\scriptscriptfont1 = \lmmv
\scriptscriptfont2 = \lmmv
\scriptscriptfont3 = \lmmv
```

(Again, I am assuming XeTeX font syntax here.)

As noted in comments, there are a large number of additional font dimensions in Unicode math fonts. LuaTeX gives these names (all listed in the LuaTeX manual), whilst for XeTeX they have numbers and are accessed using `\fontdimen`.

---

The TeX90 primitives `\delimiter`, `\mathaccent` and  `\radical` all have extended Unicode versions: `\Udelimiter`, `\Umathaccent` and  `\Uradical`. Unlike the TeX90 versions, `\Udelimiter` and `\Uradical` do not need to point to multiple glyph slots: only one slot is needed and the font shaper is responsible for growing the glyph as required. The syntax of `\Umathaccent` is significantly extended compared to `\mathaccent`, certainly for LuaTeX. All three primitives are described in the LuaTeX manual and to a lesser extend in the XeTeX one.

Comment: How `\delimiter`s, `\mathaccent`s, `\radical`s work?

Comment: I am using the lua-part of luaotfload too. I. e. not whole TeX part of `luaotfload.sty`, but directly `\directlua`. It works and gives comparable results with XeTeX's `\font` primitive (only loading time is somewhat different). You wrote that it is not working for math fonts?

Comment: I have tested this and I have found that after `\input luafonts.tex`, the LuaTeX behaves equal as XeTeX (from `\font` primitive point of view). And what is the "/OT" option in the font declaration? I removed it and it works too. I know only "/B", "/I" and "/BI" options, they are not relevant here.

Comment: @wipet Sorry if I implied things don't work with LuaTeX/math fonts: not what I meant. I was observing that not everything works as expected and there are still issues.

Comment: @wipet The `/OT` is 'OpenType' and is useful on the Mac where AAT fonts are also possible. It's included by `fontspec` as part of the basic font loading as it avoids issues in a cross-platform sense. Depending on the version of the Lua loader you use, it will offer the same syntax as XeTeX (as well as it's own native one).

Comment: Are you sure about `\let\int=∫`?  I think it should be `\let\intop=∫`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sort of :-) Will's got `∫` set up as math active so it turns into something that turns into `\intop` which ultimately uses `\Umathchar"1"00"00222B`. (This is needed as a user might directly input `∫` in a Unicode document, so you need to cover that case too.)

Answer (score 12):

The key information in the accepted answer is: load Unicode Math font
(UnMaFo) as family 2 and the same font as family 3. The TeX engine (XeTeX
or LuaTeX) re-calculates appropriate fontdimens for family 2 and family 3
from UnMaFo when these families are set.

After understanding this, I am able to do simple plain TeX macros for
unicode math. I did this in the `uni-math.tex` file released newly in the
csplain package. It was mirrored from my www pages to CTAN yesterday and it
was mirrored to TL-pretest today. The `uni-math.tex` uses straightforward
plain TeX macros (including loading fonts at arbitrary sizes; this feature
is used in OPmac macros, for example). You can compare 270 clear plain TeX
code lines of `uni-math.tex` with 5671 lines in `unicode-math.sty`. Or compare
ten milions lines of log file when simple LaTeX document (with fontspec and
unicode-math) is traced by `\tracingall` with 262k lines in log when the
same is done using `uni-math.tex`. *UnMaFo is nothig mystical*.

I try to summarize the basic information for macro programmers. If I am
wrong, please, correct me.

- There is no difference between XeTeX and LuaTeX. If LuaTeX is used, then
  you must only do `\input luafonts` to execute one `\directlua` which
  re-declares \font primitive. Now, the \font primitive in LuaTeX has
  somewhat extended syntax than in XeTeX, but using XeTeX syntax is
  sufficient and works in both engines.
- Load UnMaFo in family 2 and the same in family 3, as mentioned above. You
  can load the same in family 1 too and set all Umathcodes to family 1 as
  default. The fontfeatures must be appended by mode=base;script=math; and
  the fonts for script and scriptcsript sizes can have more fontfeatures
  +ssty=0; and +ssty=1; respectively. May be, the UnMaFo is able to deal
  with optical sizes for such cases.
- Set `\Umathcodes` for all codes from `MathClass.txt` as
  `\Umathcode<code> = <type> 1 <code>`, where  is math object type
  from TeX point of view (0 is Ord, 1 is Op, 2 is Bin etc.). Use the
  following conversion table from letters used in MathClass.txt to TeX
  types: L=1, B=2, V=2, R=3, N=0, U=0, F=0, O=4, C=5, P=6. A=7. For codes of
  type O, C and F set `\Udelcode<code> = 1 <code>`. They are extensible
  delimiters. These codes must be able to extend vertically if UnMaFo is
  correctly prepared. Note `1` in settings: this is family 1 where UnMaFo is
  loaded.
- Now, the Math typesetting is prepared. But you must use correct unicode
  codes between `$...$`, no control sequences. Especially, you must use
  direct codes for math italic, because codes  `` `A-`Z, `a-`z `` are set as
  roman upright in Unicode table. This is not comfortable. Moreover, we (TeX
  users) are lazy and we write `{\cal A}` instead of selecting the proper
  unicode calligraphic A in text editor when preparing the source of the
  document.
- To prepare such Math alphabet selectors like `\cal` we must know, that all
  Math alphabets are in one font at given codes, so switching by
  `\fam=something` is bad. We use "base-code sets"  `` `A-`Z, `a-`z `` for
  roman Latin characters,  `` `0-`9 `` for digits and `"391-"3D5` for Greek
  characters. The macros like `\cal` changes the `\Umathcodes` of characters
  in appropriate base-code set. So, user can write `A` from base-code set
  and it creates calligraphic A when `\cal` was used.
- There are following Math alphabets in UnMaFo: rm, bf, it and bi of Latin
  roman and Greek; sans, bfsans, itsans and bisans of Latin; bfsans and
  bisans of Greek; cal, bfcal frak, bffrak of Latin; doublestroked of
  latin; rm, bf, sans, bfsans, doublestroked of digits; typewriter of Latin
  and digits, see http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf. When
  preparing `\cal`-like macros, you must to set new codes from whole
  base-set using `\Umathcode <base-code> = 7 1 <new-code>` in a loop. But
  there is a little problem with absurd holes in the Math alphabets in
  Unicode table (see the document above). So, a little macro programming
  must be done. For example, you can see the macro `\umathcharholes` in
  `uni-math.tex`.
- If you have prepared `\itlatin`, `\itgreekrmGreek` macros similar to
  `\cal` mentioned above, then you can set `\itlatin \itgreekrmGreek` as
  default. This is normal behaviour in TeX.
- Typical control sequences used in TeX's math mode (like `\sum`, `\pm`,
  `\oplus`) can be scanned from `unicode-math-table.tex` file. You can set
  most of these control sequences as an equivalent of direct `\Umathcode` by
  `\Umathcharnumdef<sequence>=\Umathcodenum<code>`.
- The codes with type L (declared in `MathClass.txt`) have two (or more) sizes
  in good prepared UnMaFo. So different sizes will be used in `\textstyle`
  and `displaystyle` automatically.
- The control sequences declared as `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` in
  `unicode-math-table.tex` can be defined as macro with `\Udelimiter` which
  simply points to its code. So `\langle`, `\rangle`, `\lbrace` etc. will
  work in the context of `\left...\right`. See the scanning process of
  `MathClass.txt` and `unicode-math-table.tex` in `uni-math.tex` file for more
  details.
- The codes declared as D (diacritics) in `MathClass.txt` can be used as
  `\Umathaccent` argument. This primitive declares extensive math accent
  (like `\widetilde`) as default. The feature of extensibility is prepared
  in UnMaFo for such codes. Unextensible accents must be declared by keyword
  "fixed", extensible bottom placed accents have "bottom" keyword in
  `\Umathaccent`. Define "fixed" math accents for all sequences from
  `unicode-math-table.tex` where `\mathaccent` type is mentioned. Next,
  define more flexible accents using `\Umathaccent` for control sequences
  `\overbrace`, `\underbrace`, `\overparen`, `\underparen`, `\overbracket`,
  `\underbracket`, `\widehat`, `\widetilde`, `\overleftharpoon`,
  `\overrightharpoon`, `\overleftarrow`, `\overrightarrow`,
  `\overleftrightarrow`.
- Define `\sqrt`, `\cuberoot` and `\fourthroot` by `\Uradical` primitive
  wich points to the codes "221A, "0221B, "0221C. Good prepared UnMaFo
  includes more variants of these characters for different sizes.
  (Xe/Lua)TeX uses a proper size and adds the vertical bar like normal TeX
  does it when `\radical` primitive is used.
- Declare `` \Umathcode `- = 2 1 "2212 `` because we are using the hyphen character
  as minus symbol in math mode in TeX.
- Define `\let\intop=\int  \def\int{\intop \nolimits}` in order to keep the
  plainTeX behavior of integral operator. Similarly, do this for other
  integral-like symbols if you want. Declare integral code as
  inmath-active and do the similar trick if you want to use direct integral
  symbol instead `\int` in the document.

More fonts can be loaded to next families 4, 5, 6, etc. It is irrelevant
what type of font it is: UnMaFo or Text Unicode or classical 8bit. Then you
can switch to usage of characters from such fonts by \fam=number, if the
given code has a type 7.

Unfortunately, there isn't complete bold math version of common UnMaFo, only
specific math alphabets have bf variant, no other symbols. We need complete
math bold in titles where bold text font is used. I used "poor bold" for
such case implemented by `2 Tr` PDF operator.