Too many \setmathfont leads to "Too many symbol fonts declared" error
Since my usual math font configuration is patched up using characters from several different fonts such as KpMath-Regular, KpMath-Sans, texgyrepagella-math, Asana-Math, latinmodern-math, etc. and with different scales even for characters in the same font (to make the final result more consistent), it already takes enough slots for math font declaration.
(Below is some related code taken from my document class.)
\PassOptionsToPackage { warnings-off = { mathtools-colon, mathtools-overbracket } } { unicode-math }
\RequirePackage { unicode-math }
\unimathsetup { math-style = ISO, partial = upright, nabla = upright }
\setmathfont [ RawFeature = mathkern ] { KpMath-Regular.otf }
\setmathfont { KpMath-Regular.otf }
  [
    range = \amalg ,
    Scale = 0.84625
  ]
\setmathfont { KpMath-Sans.otf }
  [
    range = { \sum }
  ]
\setmathfont { latinmodern-math.otf }
  [
    range = { frak, bffrak, \mitvarpi, \mupvarpi, \ast } ,
    Scale = 1.10
  ]
\setmathfont { texgyrepagella-math.otf }
  [
    range = { `(, `), `/, \setminus, `| } ,
    Scale = 1.10
  ]
\setmathfont { texgyrepagella-math.otf }
  [
    range = { \mathcomma, \mathsemicolon } ,
  ]
\setmathfont [ RawFeature = mathkern ] { Asana-Math.otf }
  [
    range = { it / { Latin, latin }, bfit / { Latin, latin }, up / num, bfup / num }
  ]
\setmathfont { KpMath-Regular.otf } [ range = { cal, bfcal }, RawFeature=+ss01 ]

Now that I would like to add a few more lines as below (in the configuration file of another package, not directly in the document class, so the order matters) for typesetting functors, I encounter the errors Too many symbol fonts declared and Symbol font ``__um_fam9' not defined.
\setmathsf{Palatino Sans LT Pro}
% \setmathfont{PalatinoSansLTPro-Regular}[range=sfup]
\setmathfont{PalatinoSansLTPro-LightIta}[range=sfit]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={}] % reset the metric

Would there be some way to overcome this issue? I really wish to keep my current selection of math characters since I have been using them like this for more than three years, in many documents.

Below, I hope, would be a valid MWE: the main math font configuration is hided in simplivre.cls, which is already contained in a usual TeX distribution (I cannot seem to be able to extract the corresponding code in order to build a MWE with the same errors, sorry). This MWE reports Too many symbol fonts declared error on my side.
\documentclass{simplivre}

\usepackage{mathrsfs} % introduced by another package, I cannot cancel this

\setmathsf{Palatino Sans LT Pro} % one may replace this with any other font if needed
\setmathfont{PalatinoSansLTPro-LightIta}[range=sfit]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={}] % reset the metric

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}


you are using luatex or xetex and unicode-math so you have 256 rather than 16 math \fam available, however LaTeX can only use these "out of the box"  for math alphabets, it can not use them for classic symbol fonts as the latex declarations (in packages other than unicode-math) resolve to the classic \mathchardef which can only access 16 \fam.  So usually you can access more fam by dropping down to \Umath... primitive declarations but it depends on the details

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for the information! If I understand your suggestion properly, should I replace those instance of \setmathfont where only a few symbols are introduced by primitive declarations using \Umathcode, I would be able to free the previous usage of families, is that correct? However, as an example, for \amalg taken from KpMath-Regular.otf with scale 0.84625, how should I express these info using \Umathcode? The only reference I could find is  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308768 , but it doesn't seem to have mentioned font and scale.

I posted a second version...

You are using luatex or xetex and unicode-math so you have 256 rather than 16 math \fam available, however LaTeX can only use these "out of the box" for math alphabets, it can not use them for classic symbol fonts as the latex declarations (in packages other than unicode-math) resolve to the classic \mathchardef which can only access 16 \fam. So usually you can access more fam by dropping down to \Umath... primitive declarations but it depends on the details...
Here though, I take a slightly different approach: this lets unicode-math make the allocations but then the log shows the last successful one is
\sym__um_fam8=\mathgroup15

so all 16 classic \fam are used (0-15)
The following moves \sym__um_fam8 to an (arbitrary) high fam of 100 and resets the fam (mathgroup) allocator (\count18) back one which allows the final \setmathfont to succeeed.
This runs without error but to be honest I haven't traced if this catches everywhere that needs catching. If a declaration has been made by this point that has pre-expanded \sym__um_fam8 to 15 then the definition will need to be adjusted to use 100 instead, but as long as it only uses the name then things should be fine.
This is of course a hack, but points to a real fix which would be to adjust unicode-math to always or via a key on the \setmathfont allow itself to use the \fam beyond 16.
\documentclass{simplivre}

\usepackage{mathrsfs} % introduced by another package, I cannot cancel this

\setmathsf{Palatino Sans LT Pro} % one may replace this with any other font if needed
\setmathfont{PalatinoSansLTPro-LightIta}[range=sfit]

\expandafter\chardef\csname sym__um_fam8\endcsname=100
\advance\count18 -1

\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={}] % reset the metric

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}


Plan b is to simply allow the allocator to use 256 \fam rather than 16, but as noted above this is only safe if the only allocations following this will use unicode aware \Umath... allocations (which unicode-math does).
It just replaces 15 by 255 in one place.
\documentclass{simplivre}

\usepackage{mathrsfs} % introduced by another package, I cannot cancel this

\makeatletter
% do this after any "classic" allocations such as mathrsfs

\makeatletter
\def\DeclareSymbolFont@m@dropped #1#2#3#4#5{%
 \@tempswafalse
 \edef\reserved@b{#2}%
 \def\cdp@elt##1##2##3##4{\def\reserved@c{##1}%
      \ifx\reserved@b\reserved@c \@tempswatrue\fi}%
 \cdp@list
 \if@tempswa
   \@ifundefined{sym#1}{%
      \ifnum\count18< 255 % was 15 %
        \expandafter\new@mathgroup\csname sym#1\endcsname
        \expandafter\new@symbolfont\csname sym#1\endcsname
                        {#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
      \else
         \@latex@error{Too many symbol fonts declared}\@eha
      \fi
     }%
     {%
      \@font@info{Redeclaring symbol font `#1'}%
      \def\group@elt##1##2{%
           \noexpand\group@elt\noexpand##1%
           \expandafter\ifx\csname sym#1\endcsname##1%
             \expandafter\noexpand\csname#2/#3/#4/#5\endcsname
           \else
               \noexpand##2%
           \fi}%
      \xdef\group@list{\group@list}%
      \def\version@elt##1{%
          \expandafter
          \SetSymbolFont@\expandafter##1\csname#2/#3/#4/#5\expandafter
              \endcsname \csname sym#1\endcsname
          }%
      \version@list
     }%
  \else
    \@latex@error{Encoding scheme  `#2' unknown}\@eha
  \fi
  }
\makeatother
  
\setmathsf{Palatino Sans LT Pro} % one may replace this with any other font if needed
\setmathfont{PalatinoSansLTPro-LightIta}[range=sfit]


\errorcontextlines=1000
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={}] % reset the metric

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}


Thank you for the simple quick hack and for the newly added Plan B! They both seem to work fine in my document. As my configuration file shall be loaded only at begindocument/before, Plan B seems to be more reliable and I might just stick to it for the moment :)

This is longstanding issue it would be nice to have it fixed upstream as the constraint appears to be only that old packages using \mathchardef should be used first.

@user691586 where "used first" is a bit tricky as lots of these packages delay stuff in the begin document hook, but yes it doesn't make a lot of sense to restrict to 16 here. (the original incorporation of lua/xetex into the format allowed the full range but broke too much which is why the format allows 256 \fam to be allocated (and used for math alphabets) but only 16 for symbol fonts. 16 full unicode fonts is still a lot more that 16 126 character OT1... fonts:-) but unicode-math does use quite a lot as we see here....
