# Unicode-math, range and $\big( \big)$ issue

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I wanted to uses a different `\ell` from that in XITS, so I thought I'd try an interesting feature of unicode-math.sty allowing for the use of multiple fonts.

The following code (MacTeX 2016, recently updated) works for the `\ell` but causes another unexpected problem:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}[range={"2113},Scale=0.8]
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

$\big( \big)$

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: with boxes]

The little boxes indicate missing glyphs. If I comment-out the second \setmathfont line:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
%\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}[range={"2113},Scale=0.8]
\usepackage{microtype}
```

the output is normal:

[image: without boxes]

Am I misunderstanding this? Or, hopefully, is there a fix/workaround?

Comment: Use LuaTeX.  Math typesetting in XeTeX is [just broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549) and I honestly don't think that this will ever be fixed.

Comment: Found unicode-math solution at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/344​

Comment: @HenriMenke On reflection, I think the 'just broken' description is a bit unfair. As to your suggestion to use LuaTeX: I think not -- an uncertain life perpetually on the bleeding edge is not in the least attractive to me.

Comment: The bug has been fixed with `unicode-math` version 0.8j, released 2018-01-07.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the bug has been fixed, making the question no longer relevant.