# Spacing in \frac with xelatex and unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, spacing, xetex, unicode-math, fractions

If I compile the following MWE with xelatex, it yields fraction lines at different heights in the second fraction. If I compile it with lualatex, that doesn't happen. If I omit the first fraction, it doesn't happen. If I omit `unicode-math`, it doesn't happen. (If I omit `unicode-math`, `fontspec` and use LaTeX, dvips and ps2pdf, it doesn't happen.)

Is that correct behaviour (if yes, for which engine?) and I should use other spacing code in the fraction (I need blank fractions) or is this a bug (in the other engine)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\frac{a}{b}\) \(\frac{\hspace*{1cm}}{\hspace*{1cm}}=\frac{\hspace*{1cm}}{\hspace*{1cm}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks like a bug to me luatex with fontspec gives the same height bar in all three fractions

Comment: it is unrelated to the blanks, you get the same from `\(\frac{a}{b}\) \(\frac{a}{b}\) `  the first fraction always uses a thicker rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug has been fixed. In miktex (which has a newer xetex) the output is correct.

[image]

See also [Why is the fraction off the math axis in XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549/why-is-the-fraction-off-the-math-axis-in-xetex)