# newtxmath + Libertine + fontspec

Tags: fontspec, libertine, newtxmath

For a document I'm writing with XeLaTeX, I have to use Times New Roman as a main font. For math environment only, I'd like to use newtxmath with Libertine font. For my TexShop 2016 I installed Libertine using texhash and updmap-sys (as was described in the guide). So now there're many *.tfm files of Libertine in texfm-local. I also installed *.otf Libertine fonts directly into the system.

For this simple example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\((5!)^5\)
\end{document}
```

in pdffonts I see

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
HHHARJ+txsys                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
GMSUHV+LMRoman12-Regular             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       5  0
CZQOLM+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       6  0
SRWENI+TimesNewRomanPSMT             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
```

There are no warnings in the log.

Could you please clarify the following questions

1. Am I right expecting only Libertine fonts in the pdffont's output? After all, only math environment is in the document.
2. Why do I see LMRoman and Times in the output? Shouldn't there be Libertine?
3. What is txsys?

And what can I do to fix this? As I understand, with a proper setup I should see only Libertine fonts in pdffont's output...

Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why Libertine for math in a Times context?

Comment: @egreg I was just searching for some nice fonts for math environment and newtxmath + Libertine was like the most frequently recommended option:) Unfortunately, I can't abandon Times New Roman, since its use is required in my university

Comment: Try \usepackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{libertinusmath-regular.otf}. PS: How did you install the otf fonts?

Comment: @HerbSchulz probably I should've mentioned, I'm using macOS, so to install otf fonts I just dragged them in the Font Book. Your suggestion on libertinusmath didn't work out, because fontspec error: "font libertinusmath-regular cannot be found" :(

Comment: @swasta: That's why I asked how you installed the fonts. If you installed them in the TeX Live distribution (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype) the file names should work. If you installed the Libertinus fonts (not Libertine!) via Font Book you should use \setmathfont{Libertinus Math} rather than the file name. On the other hand, if you have an updated TeX Live 2016 (you may get one more update using TeX Live Utility if you haven't updated lately) you should have the Libertinous opentype fonts already installed in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/... .

Comment: @HerbSchulz ok, I've installed Libertinius via Font Book and now \setmathfont{Libertinus Math} works properly, the same for \setmathfont{Linux Libertine O}. By the way, both these fonts are indeed in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/. Although \setmathfont{libertinusmath-regular‌​.otf} still gives "font cannot be found". Seems like I don't need \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} anymore? My text will be in Times New Roman and my math environment in Libertinus or Libertine, right?

Comment: @swasta: Yes. As far as I know Libertinus is an updated and extended Libertine.

Comment: Sometimes universities ‘require’ fonts, that is correct. However, Times New Roman is proprietary. It can hardly be expected for you to have it unless the university supplies it to you. Furthermore, I find it ugly and I have never had problems outright ignoring the font ‘requirements’. To be honest, those people who require certain fonts are usually also those who won’t recognise them. (Okay, they will realise Arial is not TNR but that’s about the end of it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*N.B.:*  Before TL 2017 is released I advise against using XeTeX for any kind of math typesetting.  There are a couple of [problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549).

It is much easier to just use `unicode-math` and the official math version of Libertine called Libertinus Math.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\((5!)^5\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is even better to substitute everything by TeX Gyre Termes, a completely free Times clone.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\((5!)^5\)
\end{document}
```

[image]