# xelatex + unicode-math + \big = ↯

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math, size, stackengine

(Note: See **EDIT** below that rules out both `stackengine` and `standalone` as the culprit)

Input:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{stackengine}\stackMath
\begin{document}
\(\bigl[
,
  \mathchoice%
  {}%
  {}%
  {}%
  {\stackunder{\scriptscriptstyle a}{}}
\bigr]\)
\end{document}
```

We expect the output `[,]` with same-size vertically aligned brackets. However, the output is as follows:

[image: output when running xelatex]

The brackets have different sizes and irregular vertical placement, which is wrong: they should have the same size and be vertically aligned. Using `\Big`, `\bigg`, etc. instead of `\big` produces similarly erroneous output. 
Removing `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, or, `\scriptscriptsize`, or, `a`, or `\stackunder` doesn't trigger the bug any more.
The compilation was done with the following software versions:

- XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.4.2)
- LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
- standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 (**NOT** responsible)
- unicode-math 2015/09/24 v0.8c
- stackengine 2016/10/04 v4.00 (**NOT** responsible)

Who is the culprit and what to do?

---

**EDIT** by S.B. Segletes

The `stackengine` package is shown **not** to be the culprit, by the following MWE, which produces the identical *wrong* result without the use of `stackengine`.  Changing `standalone` to `article` also does not correct the issue.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\bigl[
,
  \mathchoice%
  {}%
  {}%
  {}%
  {\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle a$}}
\bigr]\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: the brackets are the same size for me with xelatex in texlive 2017

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's again this one: [Why is the fraction off the math axis in XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549)  Fontdimens have been messed up (and are still not entirely correct) in XeTeX before TL2017.  Upgrade your TeXlive and you should be fine or switch to LuaTeX.

Comment: @LeonMeier I think it was a fix in the xetex binary itself so will not be available in a texlive 2016 update

Comment: I can also confirm this behavior for my MikTeX installation.  Not sure which packages or configurations need updating...

Comment: I will see if I can formulate an alternative MWE.  But it sounds like, from the comments that the culprit is Xelatex, given that it works fine in pdflatex

Comment: I have provided the MWE that excludes `stackengine` as the culprit.

Comment: Removing `unicode-math`from my MWE fixes the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be an issue with XeTeX up to version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (the one in TeX Live 2016). It doesn't happen with XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (included in TeX Live 2017).

This is the output of the original code (including `stackengine`) with the new release

[image]

This is the output of the reduced code with the new release

[image]

Comment: Would you happen to know how to tell MikTeX to update XeTeX?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Of course not. `;-)`